# AmazonServiceException NoClassDefFoundError Exception

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am trying to write an EMR code by which I can connect to RedShift and execute some queries. The code to connect to RedSHift is in Driver class of the EMR job.

This is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String ids = getAllKeys(args[0]);
    conf.set("config", ids);

    try {
        showRedShiftTableData(); //function which will connect to Redshift server
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
                + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.");
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
    //........................
    //........................
    //Other codes.
```

I have also added this configuration into my pom file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.7</version>
</dependency>
```

But When I try to run  the code on my local hadoop cluster, I am getting below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Can you please let me know what can be the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. HADOOP_CLASSPATH was not set properly. That's why hadoop was not getting the jars.